# How to invoke App.js from inner component ReactNative?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using StackNavigator to load a Tabbar created with react-native-tab-navigator in App.js. I have a view inside Tabbar. How can I navigate back to App.js from that view?

App.js

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const SigninSignup = StackNavigator({
  Signup: { screen: Signup },
  Signin: { screen: Signin },
});

 render() {
        if (this.state.condition) {
          return (<Tabbar />);
        } else {
          return (<SigninSignup />);
        }
    }
```

Myview.js (It is inside Tabbar)

How can I go back to App.js and load `SigninSignup` ?

I have tried

```
 const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
 navigate('Signin', {});
```

But getting ERROR `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navigation hierarchy starts with the `SigninSignup` navigator.

Since your component is rendering either the navigator or your tab bar according to `this.state.condition`, you can't just `navigate` to the other screen.

You con solve this be either moving the tab bar and the `SigninSignup` navigator into a new root navigator and use that to navigate between everything, or by providing a function to `Tabbar` that would change the value of `condition`:

```
<Tabbar onSomething={() => this.setState({condition: !this.state.condition})} />
```